# Using require when electron app is packaged in an asar

Tags: javascript, path, require, electron, asar

In my main.js, I have:

```
var mainFrm = require('./MainFrm');
```

This works fine except when the application is packaged as an asar file.  I get a 'Cannot find module' error.

The documentation states to use the following:

```
require('/path/to/example.asar/dir/module.js');
```

I tried that but got the same error.  Where does the path begin when using the above?  Does path start with electron.exe is?  Also, if I use require('/resources/app.asar/MainFrm.js') what path do I use for OS X apps since the Resources folder is in a different location?  What path should I use during development/debugging (i.e. not inside of an asar)

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have 2 issues. First, you may need to be explicit about the file extension, thus looking for `MainFrm.js`, not just `MainFrm`. Second, try using `resolve` to determine the name relative to the current directory.

One way to resolve this is to resolve the path at runtime, like this:

```
    var mainFrm = require("path").resolve(__dirname, "./MainFrm.js");
```

Try some combinations of that and see if it doesn't help.